# Generalized Chu-Vandermonde identity

Tags: summation

Let $m$, $n_2$ be positive integers and let $0\le j_\xi \le \delta$ for $\xi=1,2$. By applying  the Chu-Vandermonde identity several times and then resuming the resulting multiple sum  we have shown the following:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\binom{m(n_2-1) + j_1-j_2}{\delta-j_2}
=\\
&&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum\limits_{l=0}^{\delta-j_2} \binom{n_2-\xi-1}{l} \binom{j_1-j_2+\xi m}{\delta-j_2-l} \frac{d^{\delta-j_2-l}}{d x^{\delta-j_2-l}}
\left.
\frac{\left(\frac{x^m-x}{x-1}+1\right)^l x^{j_1-j_2+m \xi }}{(-\delta+j_1+l+m \xi +1)^{(\delta-j_2-l)}}
\right|_{x=1}=\\
&&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\sum\limits_{l=0}^{\delta-j_2} \binom{n_2-\xi-1}{l} \binom{j_1-j_2+\xi m}{\delta-j_2-l} 
\left\{
1_{l=0}+1_{l\ne 0}\sum\limits_{\tilde{j}=0}^{l(m-1)}\sum\limits_{\eta=0}^{l-1} 
\frac{(-1)^{\eta +\tilde{j}} \binom{l}{\eta } \binom{(l-\eta ) m}{\tilde{j}+l} (-\delta+j_2+l)^{(\tilde{j})}}{(-\delta+j_1+l+\xi  m+1)^{(\tilde{j})}}
\right\}
\end{eqnarray}
The coefficients in the sum on the right hand side clearly reduce to unity when $m=1$. Is it possible to express those coefficients in closed form, for arbitrary $m \ge 1$.?

Comment: I like more the idea of a generalized Chu-Vandermond for real index in falling factorial, if we take this form of Chu-Vandermond $(a+b)_n=\sum_k \binom{n}{k}(a)_{n-k}(b)_k$, maybe valid using some kind of incomplete gamma function, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the coefficient in curly brackets on the right hand side. The question is , is it possible to do the sum over the indices $\tilde{j}$ and $\eta$? We have found a following closed form for the sum of $\eta$. We have:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal S}_{\tilde{j}}(l,m) := \sum\limits_{\eta=0}^l (-1)^\eta \binom{l}{\eta} \binom{(l-\eta) m}{\tilde{j} + l} = \int\limits_0^{2 \pi} \left(\left(1+e^{i \phi }\right)^m-e^{i m \phi }\right)^l e^{i \phi  (\tilde{j}-l (m-1))} \frac{d \phi}{2 \pi}
\end{equation}
In particular we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal S}_{0}(l,m) &= & m^l \\
{\mathcal S}_{1}(l,m) &= & m^{l-1} \cdot \binom{m}{2} \cdot l \\
{\mathcal S}_{2}(l,m) &= & m^{l-2} \cdot (\binom{m}{2})^2 \cdot \binom{l}{2} + m^{l-1} \cdot \binom{m}{3} \cdot l \\
{\mathcal S}_{3}(l,m) &= & m^{l-3} \cdot (\binom{m}{2})^3 \cdot \binom{l}{3} + m^{l-2} \cdot \binom{m}{3} \binom{m}{2} \cdot 2 \binom{l}{2} + m^{l-1} \cdot \binom{m}{4} \cdot l \\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray}
Now, inserting the integral representation of our sum into the curly brackets we can formally do the sum over $\tilde{j}$ by using the definition of the hypergeometric function . Here we exploit the fact that the integral vanishes whenever $\tilde{j} > l (m-1)$ and therefore we can extend the summation to infinity.
Therefore we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{ \cdots \right\} = \int\limits_0^{2 \pi} F_{2,1} \left[
\begin{array}{ll} 1 && - \delta+j_2+l \\ -\delta+j_1+l+\xi m+1\end{array}; -e^{\imath \phi}
\right]
\left(\left(1+e^{i \phi }\right)^m-e^{i m \phi }\right)^l e^{i \phi  (-l (m-1))} \frac{d \phi}{2 \pi}
\end{eqnarray}
For this integral to exist we have to have $j_2 < j_1+\xi m + 1$.